# OS X El Capitan lighter font rendering for Web

Tags: css, macos, fonts, rendering, osx-elcapitan

I noticed that El Capitan renders fonts on websites way lighter/thinner than Yosemite or Marvericks. For a long time Macs rendered fonts a bit more heavy than windows would – this dosn't seem to be the case anymore for El Capitan.

The "problem"/effect is visible in all Browsers (Safari/Chrome...) and even in native apps like Spotify (wich may be based on HTML/CSS?!). I use a non retina Macbook Air. Is anyone else experiencing this? It would be interesting to know if there are changes on Retina Macs too?

Oh and in case you wonder: No, I don't mean the new system font, I'm talking about the same web font on both systems.

Do you think this is a permanent change for OS X? This would make CSS code like `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` unnecessary. Finally...

Screenshot 1: Top: Yosemite – Bottom: El Capitan

Screenshot 2: Left: Marvericks – Right: El Capitan

It's subtle but visible...

[image: Top: Yosemite – Bottom: El Capitan]

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Comment: Looks like this is the way MacOS renders fonts now... It's closer to what you will see on a retina screen.

Comment: The fonts are now pretty much what I used to see on Windows XP. Until Mavericks, everything was fine, now I miss those crispy fonts.